# How to read a space separated vector file into variables and send them to an html form using python?

Tags: python, html, forms

I'm trying to read text from a .ssv file and put them into variables so that I can submit them to an html web form.

The first piece of text is the the name of a survey, while the following pieces of text (can be any number) are questions. How can I accomplish my goal using python?

Thanks.

My data is like this:

survey1,question1,question2,question3,question4,...

I want to read those into an html form.

The answer so far tells me how to get the variables stored into python, but how would I send those to the html < form>? I'm looking online everywhere but don't really see how it's done. A link to a page telling me how, or an explanation would be amazing.

Added tags

Comment: Please provide an example of what your data looks like and what you want. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to tell from your question what it is that you want precisely, however you should use `open`. Here is an example:

```
#filename.txt
survey1,question1,question2,question3,question4
survey2,question1,question2,question3,question4
survey3,question1,question2,question3,question4
survey4,question1,question2,question3,question4
survey5,question1,question2,question3,question4

#your_script.py
values = []
with open('filename.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:   #splits on ',' as per your question example
        line = line.split(',')
        values.append((line[0],line[1:]))
>>> print(values)
[
(survey1,[question1,question2,question3,question4])
(survey2,[question1,question2,question3,question4])
(survey3,[question1,question2,question3,question4])
(survey4,[question1,question2,question3,question4])
(survey5,[question1,question2,question3,question4])
]
```

Then if you want to get the fourth question for the third survey, you can do:

`values[2][3]`

and then you can pass that to your `html` form. Preferably using a for loop for passing all the values.

OR

`survey_1_questions = values[0]`

Comment: I'm getting syntaxError: invalid syntax on 'print values'

Comment: @user3251142. You must be using python-3.x. Do `print(values)` instead

Comment: is 3.x not the best version?

Comment: and im getting SyntaxError: can't assign to function call on 'for line.split('.') in f'   , arrow pointing to 'line'.

Comment: okay, at least its working. thanks. but when i said html form, i meant html <form>. as in, I need to get each survey/question name into a variable so that i can submit them to an html website. do you know how i could do this?

Comment: if im not sure how many questions i will have, is it better to use `survey_1_questions = value[0]`?

Comment: @user3251142. In that case yes.